# Django CreateView - created_by, modified_by mixin not working

Tags: django

I have followed spapas tutorial on CBV's and tried to apply a mixin on a create view. But looks like it doesn't evaluate correctly the if not form.invoice.requester for a user foreign key because it always says: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist and it points to the field evaluated in the **if not** line.

What can be wrong?

## views.py

```
class AuditableMixin(object, ):
def form_valid(self, form, ):
    if not form.instance.requester:
        form.instance.requester = self.request.user
    form.instance.modified_by = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

class NewOrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, AuditableMixin, generic.CreateView):
    permission_required = 'orders.add_order'
    form_class = NewOrderForm
    model = Order
    title = 'New Order'
    extra_context = {'title': title}
```

## forms.py

```
class NewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        widgets = {
            'order_details': forms.Textarea,
        }
        exclude = (
            'status',
            'invoice',
            'requester',
            'modified_by',
        )
```

## models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('open', 'Open'),
    ('inprogress', 'In Progress'),
    ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
    ('closed','Closed'),
    ('resolved','Resolved'),
)

subject = models.CharField(
    max_length=30,
)

requester = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='orders',

)

order_details = models.TextField(

)

created = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True,
)

updated = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now=True,
)

status = models.CharField(
    max_length=12,
    default='open',
    choices= STATUS_CHOICES,
)

invoice = models.ForeignKey(
    Invoice,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank= True,
    null=True,
    related_name='orders',
)

modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='orders_modified',
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subject

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('Order_Detail', args=[str(self.pk)])

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your `Order` model or how `requester` is related to `Order`.

Comment: Calling `requester` on a model instance actually performs the query to fetch the related object, so it fails with the error you see if it the ForeignKey is null. try: `if not form.instance.requester_id` instead.

Comment: What to say? Thank you! I couldn't understand why it didn't evaluate the expression. It WORKS now. You can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the ForeignKey object on a model, you're actually telling Django to perform the query to fetch the related object. To check if the relationship exists, you should check `<fieldname>_id` which is the actual name of the field:

```
if not form.instance.requester_id:
    form.instance.requester = self.request.user
```

That way if `requester_id` is `None` you don't perform the query, which would through the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error.